# Which parameter do we check to see the performance of cards

Tags: operating-system

I was just wondering what parameters do we use to check the performance of card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot, like sequential read speed, random read speed, sequential write speed, sequential read speed, burst speed, etc. Even some of these depend on the part of the disk you are testing.

You can check what disk benchmark softwares do to answer your question.

http://www.hdtune.com/

http://www.attotech.com/disk-benchmark/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_Tach (RIP)

http://www.passmark.com/products/pt_advdisk.htm